# iPhone productivity app that tracks hours worked with an efficiency parameter

Tags: ios, software-recommendation, productivity

I'm looking for an iPhone app that tracks "effective" hours worked over time.

Say I feel half efficient. Then two hours 'effort' amounts to 1 hour of 'actual' work done. If I'm at say 33% efficiency, for example, then when 3 hours go by, I know I've done about an hour's worth of real work.

And perhaps it plots time worked on a line graph over the long term. So I know how many hours I've worked today, or the past week, or in January.

The efficiency aspect is key, and it's the main feature I'm looking for. Does an app like this exist?

Answer (score -1):

When I get grilled to account for every move I make I just look at my emails and history and the time frame from there. I don't know if the computer can determine what is the difference though. There might be setting as if you were a parent ant wanting to know what exactly you kids are doing that can help with that. You could make 2 accounts on the computer and use one for work and one for other.